# One input not posting PHP/MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

Trying to use this page to update an MSSQL table. My hidden field named hdnLine (2nd to last line of code) is not being posted on submit, though it is being populated with a value prior to the form being submitted. I had the page working, and all of the sudden I keep getting "Notice: Undefined index: hdnLine in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\clientadmin\agent-edit.php on line 11" when I try to submit. I have been messing with it all day trying to debug etc. and have had no luck with it. I'm assuming its a syntax error of sorts but can't figure it out. Any help would be gladly appreciated. The code is all below minus a few includes for db connectivity. I will do my best to help answer any questions pertaining.

```
<?php
if($_GET["Action"]=="Save"){

    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST["hdnLine"];$i++)
    {
        $strSQL = "UPDATE RENTAGNT SET ";
        $strSQL .="SPIFF = '".$_POST["txtSPIFF$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",PROMO = '".$_POST["txtPROMO$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",SPIFFVAL = '".$_POST["txtSPIFFVAL$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",AGNTLVL = '".$_POST["txtAGNTLVL$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",SPIFFDAYS = '".$_POST["txtSPIFFDAYS$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",MASTAGNTID = '".$_POST["txtMASTAGNTID$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .="WHERE RENTAGNTID = '".$_POST["hdnRENTAGNTID$i"]."' ";
            $stmt = $conn->query($strSQL);
    }
    //exit();
}

$strSQL="SELECT RENTAGNTID, RENTAGNT.AGENTCODE, NAME, AGNTLVL,SPIFF, SPIFFVAL, PROMO, SPIFFDAYS,INACTIVE, MASTAGNTID FROM RENTAGNT WHERE INACTIVE='0' GROUP BY MASTAGNTID, RENTAGNT.AGENTCODE, RENTAGNT.NAME, RENTAGNTID, SPIFF, SPIFFVAL, SPIFFDAYS, AGNTLVL, INACTIVE, PROMO";

            $stmt = $conn->query($strSQL); 
?>  

       <form name="frmMain" method="POST" action="?Action=Save" >

<table id="res-list-table" class="tablesorter" width="90%" border="1" background="#fff">
 <thead> <tr>
    <th width="10%"> <div align="center">Rental Agent ID</div></th>
    <th width="20%"> <div align="center">Agent Code </div></th>
    <th width="35%"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">1 Free</div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">Spiff Yes/No</div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">Spiff Amount </div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">Days Req. <br/> for Spiff</div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">Master Agent</div></th>
    <th width="5%"> <div align="center">Agent Level</div></th>
  </tr>
  </thead><tbody>


<?php
$i = 1;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
    $i++;
?>

  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
    <?php echo $row["RENTAGNTID"]; ?>
    </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
    <?php echo $row["AGENTCODE"]; ?>
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
    <?php echo $row["NAME"]; ?>
    </div></td>  

    <td>

        <input type="hidden" name="hdnRENTAGNTID<?=$i;?>" size="6" value="<?=$row["RENTAGNTID"];?>"/>

    <select name="txtPROMO<?=$i;?>">    
<option value="0" <?php if($row["PROMO"]=="0") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >No</option>
<option value="1" <?php if($row["PROMO"]=="1") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >Yes</option>

</select></td>
<td>
    <select name="txtSPIFF<?=$i;?>">    
<option value="0" <?php if($row["SPIFF"]=="0") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >No</option>
<option value="1" <?php if($row["SPIFF"]=="1") { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >Yes</option>
</select></td>


    <td><input type="text" name="txtSPIFFVAL<?=$i;?>" size="5" style="width:75px;" value="<?=$row["SPIFFVAL"];?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtSPIFFDAYS<?=$i;?>" size="5" style="width:75px;" value="<?=$row["SPIFFDAYS"];?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtMASTAGNTID<?=$i;?>" size="5" style="width:75px;" value="<?=$row["MASTAGNTID"];?>" /></td>
<td>
    <select name="txtAGNTLVL<?=$i;?>">    
<option value="1" <?php if($row["AGNTLVL"]==1) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >Agent</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($row["AGNTLVL"]==2) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >Master Agent</option>
<option value="3" <?php if($row["AGNTLVL"]==3) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >Admin</option>
</select>

</td>

  </tr>

<?php
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnLine" value="<?=$i;?>"/>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the short tags used to assign the value for the `<input type="hidden" name="hdnLine" value="<?=$i;?>"/>`. Is the `short_open_tag = On` in your php.ini?
If not change to `on`.

Or

Change throughout the code where `<?=?>` to `<?php=?>`

Comment: I would also recommend to test and see if <?php echo $i;?> will do the job to retrieve the $i and if thats the case - your suspicion of the short open tag to be off is justified.

Comment: I have tried both turning on short_open_tag as well as changing everything to <?php echo $i;?> when i view the source all of the values for $i are populating appropriately. When I submit and do var_dump($_POST); I see that all fields aside from the final hdnLine field are being posted.

Comment: Also once you change to `short_open_tag = On` restart the Apache web server. Can you please paste the `view source of the page`